# Angellist api not returning data in foreach loop

Tags: php, api

I grabbed the data with the following code:

```
$angellist = file_get_contents('https://api.angel.co/1/startups/6702/jobs');
```

When i print $angellist i get the data returned on my screen. So everything is fine until the next step.

When i use a foreach loop and i print out $list, nothing shows. What am i missing?

```
        foreach($angellist as $list):

            pr($list);

            endforeach;
```

If you need more information, I am happy to oblige.

Comment: have you first decode the response with json_decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode it using JSON to convert it into array and use it in foreach loop.Use the code below

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents('https://api.angel.co/1/startups/6702/jobs');
$angellist = json_decode($url,true);
 foreach($angellist as $list):

            pr($list);

            endforeach;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Right on the money. Thank you for your fast response!